# Problems with CodeIgniter Languages

Tags: codeigniter-2

I'm trying to make my site multi-lingual. I've created 2 folders and 2 files so far:

```
/application/language/en-us/
/application/language/en-us/application_lang.php
/application/language/fr-ca/
/application/language/fr-ca/application_lang.php
```

In the language files, I have the following declarations:

```
$lang['lang_company_name'] = 'Hello'; // en-us
$lang['lang_company_name'] = 'World'; // fr-ca
```

Then my test code:

```
$this->lang->load('application', 'en-us');
echo $this->lang->line('lang_company_name');
$this->lang->load('application', 'fr-ca');
echo $this->lang->line('lang_company_name');
```

The output is: `HelloHello`. Why am I not getting `HelloWorld`?

**UPDATE:**

- autoload.php has nothing for `$autoload['language']`.
- config.php still has `$config['language'] = 'english'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first language you load becomes the default language. If you did that in the opposite order you'd get "worldworld".

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie You don't switch languages mid page load. What you'd do is set the language before you do anything else (and set it only once)

Answer (score 0):

Once you load the language, it keeps track that the "application" language file has been loaded. So once it has been loaded, the 2nd call doesn't actually do anything since it sees it as loaded (it ignores the 2nd parameter when keeping track of loaded files).

Looking at the code here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/master/system/core/Lang.php, it looks like you might be able to hack it so it loads it again (unset from the $is_loaded attribute), but I guess the better question might be why do you need to do this? Somehow it seems a bit odd loading 2 different language files!

Comment: I'm not trying to load 2 language files. I'm trying to switch languages. The test code is just to see if I could do it.

Comment: What if you run just `$this->lang->load('application', 'fr-ca');
echo $this->lang->line('lang_company_name');`? Do you then "World" outputted? The language selection is going to happen once per page load anyway, so this will show you if the selection actually works or not!